# Data structure - Check if array contain 2 integers that the first one is bigger by 2 times from the second one

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I wanted to know if there is a way to check if an array contain 2 integers (integer > 0) that the first one is exactly 2 times from the second.

e.g:

```
44 6 2 5 9 22 5 3 4 31
```

2 and 4 should return true.

How can I do it in time complexity of O(n)?

Answer (score 4):

Hash each integer.  For each integer x, check if 2*x is in the hash table.  This is O(n) for the hashing, and O(1) for each check, so the total complexity is O(n).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But when i`m checking each x if 2*x is in the hash table the time complexity is O(n^2) no?

Comment: No.  For each x, checking if 2*x is in the hash table is a constant time operation.  You check n numbers, so the total is O(n).

Comment: @Trying_To_Understand You're making two linear passes through the array, so the time taken is still O(n), although a bit worse than you could do with a single pass through the array. You could meld aspects of this answer (using a hash table), with aspects of Lior's answer (checking for both /2 and *2) to come up with a fairly simple and performant single pass solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in O(n) time using O(2^m) memory, where m is the number of bits per input element.

Assuming that the input elements are m-bit integers (their range is 0..(2^m)-1):

**A one-pass solution:**

- Define array *a* of size 2^m bits (= 2^(m-3) bytes):
- Zero array *a*
- For each source element *e*:

  - If *e* is even

    - if *a*[*e*/2]==1 then found
  - If *e* < 2^(m-1)

    - if *a*[*e* *2]==1 then found
  - Set *a*[*e*] = 1

**Improving memory requirements:**

- There is no need to store any odd integer e > 2^(m-1) since both e/2 and e*2 are unfeasible. This saves 25%.
- A two-pass solution: in the 1st pass store only even integers and in the 2nd pass search for 2*e. This saves 50%

---

Hash table would give you O(n) amortized (not worst-case) and requires less memory only when the input set is small (you'll need to store the values themselves, use large table to avoid frequent collisions, manage lists, etc.)

Comment: Is this really `O(n)` memory? The size of the array, and hence the memory used, would be dependent on the size of the largest number, no? I would imagine the memory usage is some function of `m`.

Comment: This is a very carefully thought out and performant answer, but maybe it is possible to do a bit better. Since we're only interested in powers of 2, maybe indexing our cache by log to the base 2 of e (i.e. the power of 2 that the number is). Then you can check whether a[log_2(e) +1] or a[log_2(e) - 1] exists, and return true if found. This would be O(m) in memory.

Comment: @Asad: Why limit our interest to powers of 2?